# how to implement Action<..> as Func<...>

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, delegates, func

I'd like to implement Action as func and get the error : could not use void in this context.
Please advise

```
Action<string> someFunc_1 = Console.WriteLine;
someFunc_1("Test");

Func<string, void> someFunc_2 = Console.WriteLine;
```

Comment: Void isn't a type, it's special. And why not tell us *why* you would want to do this, so we could possibly help you with another, better solution? =)

Comment: curious why you do this?

Comment: A `Func` is supposed to return a result. What do you expect it to return after doing a `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: Your incorrect "Func<string, void>" is equivalent to Action<string>, because don't return result.

Comment: thank you all. just learning some stuff :). I read that :"Action<string> is equivalent to Func<string, void>" tried to implement it and got the compile error. so the answer is - Action is the only out of the box way to use when returning void :)

Comment: it's even just done for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Action<T1, T2, ...>` is done to replace `Func<T1, T2, ..., void>`.

You can't use `void` in a generic. It's not a type in C#.

Then in your case, use `Action<string>` instead of `Func<string, void>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Func<string, bool> someFunc_2 = s =>
{
  Console.WriteLine(s);
  return true;
};
```